# Rotating a standard HTML5 slider using CSS

Tags: css, html, sliders

I am trying to rotate a standard slider 90 deg (pi/2) after reading the CSS rotate property reference guide but so far it remains in its default position.  The documentation did state its for a block element so I wrapped the slider within a div but still no success.

HTML:

```html
<div id="sliders">

<form id="form" name="form1">
<p>
Slider 1
<input id="slider01" autocomplete="off" type="range" name="slider1" min="0" max="10" value="0"><span id="value">0</span>
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</p>
</form>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#sliders {
rotation-point: 50% 50%;
rotation: 90deg;    
}
```

Comment: Note: according to HTML5 CR, clause 10.5., it should be possible to make the slider vertical simply by setting `height` larger than `width`, but this currently works in Opera only. If it ever gets wider support, it should be a better approach than transforms.

Comment: That does sound like a more simple solution when its fully supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rotation` property is not supported by any browser yet. Use `transform` instead. Remember to add browser specific prefixes

```css
#sliders {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

To manage the **rotation point** you should use `transform-origin`

```css
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: I see, thanks, I've just implemented the code and even though my slider is wrapped within a paragraph the slider seems to be overlapping with all my other elements.

Comment: @user1574598, can you provide an example (like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) and explain what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I'll try and do that, just need to understand how to use it first.